# How to change item's layout in the grid view in code

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-8

I have a grid view with custom groups. 
In `MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector` I define what template to use. 
Using [this post](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/03/07/Databinding-to-the-VariableSizedWrapGrid-in-Windows-8-Metro.aspx) I've created the following layout.
[image]
**How I can resize the first item in "News 1" to fill the whole available content?**

Here is code of my grid:

```
class ResizableGridView : GridView
    {
        protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
        {
            var viewModel = item as IResizable;

            if (viewModel != null && viewModel.Width != 0 && viewModel.Height != 0)
            {
                element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpanProperty, 2);
                element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, 2);
            }

            base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        }
    }


 <resizeableGrid:ResizableGridView
            x:Name="itemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Padding="116,137,40,46"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource mySelector}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsSwipeEnabled="false"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
```

And the code of the item template that is used.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="tmp170x170ItemTemplate">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="170" Height="170">
                <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                </Border>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="30" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to set static grid's cell Height and Width, like this:

```
 <GroupStyle.Panel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0" ItemHeight="10" ItemWidth="10"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </GroupStyle.Panel>
```

And now, in code, while setting ColumnSpan/RowSpan you can easily set custom size. So if you want cell to be 500 x 200, you should set:

```
 element.SetValue(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpanProperty, 50);
 element.SetValue(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, 20);
```

And, to remove Height/Width on DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="VariableSizeItemTemplate">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                </Border>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="30" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width and height properties from your ítem template, like so:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="tmp170x170ItemTemplate">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="30" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Even if I remove "size" and then I set image to the 1st item larger then to the rest of the items, smaller items are being re-sized to the same size as the 1st, biter one.

Comment: Btw, your RowSpan and ColSpan should be in the PrepareContainerForItemOverride method. Can you post the code where you're assigning first element Row and Col span?

Answer (score 0):

Your all steps very good.
But, if you set item width, item height in your datatemplate; all items have a standart sizes. Item template must be flexible layout this situation.
This solution be resolved your requests:

```
protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject element, object item)
{
    base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);

    try
    {
        dynamic _item = item;
        element.SetValue(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpanProperty, _item.ColSpan);
        element.SetValue(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, _item.RowSpan);

    }
    catch
    {
        element.SetValue(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpanProperty, 1);
        element.SetValue(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, 1);
    }
    finally
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    }
}
```

If you don't use a ColumnSpanProperty,RowSpanProperty; change "if" code conditions.

and your datatemplate can be like this:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NewsShowCaseItemTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="6">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="110" Height="110">
                <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Summary}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Regards;)